# AJAX загрузка страниц. Отслеживание нажатие колесика на мыши

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть функция для подгрузи страниц по url, вызывается на ссылках. Как мне отследить нажатие колесика? Для открытия страницы в новом окне.
На примере **ВКонтакте**.

Функция для понимания

```
function uGetPage ( uUrl, uStatus )
{
    uUrl = (uStatus) ? uUrl : $(uUrl).attr('href');

    mousedown(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(event.button == 1)
        {
            // Здесь открытие нового окна
            return false;
        }
    });

    //Если нет нажатие колесика, подгружаем страницу
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

Comment: Ни чего интересного не нашел

Comment: Вам необходимо обрабатывать событие клика колесика мышки по определенной группе элементов(правда Я так и не понял зачем это)? Приведенная мною библиотека позволяет это реализовать.